# Displaying Overlapping BufferedImages in Java

Tags: java

I was wondering if anyone knows how to display multiple (probably just 2) `BufferedImage`s overlapping each other; in other words, using `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` for the top image I want to be able to superimpose one image above the other, while still being able to view the lower image depending on alpha values.

The way I am familiar with displaying them is as an `ImageIcon` attached to a `JLabel`, ie:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("");
myLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myBufferedImage));
```

As far as I know, this method doesn't seem conducive to layering `BufferedImage`s over one another and so I am looking for an alternative method of doing this.

Alternatively if you know a way I could layer the images (without drawing one to the other) while still using the `ImageIcon` that would be great as well.

Comment: What's the use case? If you just want to display a non-interactive image, use a JPanel with a custom `paintComponent` method.

Comment: @Saposhiente Basically I am writing a simple MS Paint-like program and I want to be able to see the shape I'm drawing (by dragging) in a separate `BufferedImage` over the main image without affecting the main one. (if that makes any sense).

Comment: And then once the mouse releases, the final new shape will be drawn to the base image.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, this method doesn't seem conducive to layering BufferedImages over one another and so I am looking for an alternative method of doing this.

You can add any component to a JLabel, so you could add a second label to the first label:

```
JLabel topLabel = new JLabel(...);
topLabel.setSize( topLabel.getPreferredSize();
topLabel.setLocation(10, 10);
myLabel.add( topLabel );
```

Or maybe a better approach is to use a `JLayeredPane` which allows you to stack multiple components on top of one another. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for a working example.

Comment: If a second label is added to the first one, can it be displayed in the same space?